"Top Answer" on network profile shows incorrect vote total (off-by-three)
My top answer on the StackExchange network shows on my Network Profile as having a vote total of 1835:

However, the same post has a total score of 1832 (+1833/-1) on Stack Overflow:

The post has been locked for nearly a year (since December 2023) so it's unlikely this is a caching delay.
I don't mind the extra apparent upvotes, but it's a bit odd that the score would be wrong. It's not the only question affected either; a random check showed that What does "(void)!ptr" do?, which appears on the tenth page of the Top Answers list, shows 10 on Network Profile but 9 on Stack Overflow. (I did receive the Nice Answer badge for that answer, so this is likely due to a retracted upvote or something like that).
This question is similar to Top Network Posts showing incorrect score, Answers in top Network Posts showing incorrect score, Question Score incorrect on StackExchange profile page, Top Answers in network profile shows incorrect score, although in this case the score is off by 3 instead of just off by 1.
